# Capturing/Selecting images and returning its type

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I allow the user to choose between capturing an image or selecting it from the gallery, and I want to know the type of the photo afterwards (PNG/JPG).
I'm using this code but it is not working well.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                mImg.setImageBitmap(photo);
            } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
                CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
                        null);
                Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

                Bitmap bm;
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
                int scale = 1;
                while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                        && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    scale *= 2;
                options.inSampleSize = scale;
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);

                mImg.setImageBitmap(bm);
                mImg.setAlpha(1);

            }
}
}
```

Comment: why do you want to know the type (PNG/JPEG) of image?

Comment: you may check it from imagepath that gives extention

Comment: @MukeshRana I want to use it later on with ParseFile

Comment: @MaheshGiri How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know the type of the photo afterwards (PNG/JPG)

Call `getType()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in the `Uri`.

> I'm using this code but it is not working well.

Delete most of what you have, as your `selectedImagePath` code will fail on most Android devices and you are decoding the bitmap on the main application thread. Use [an image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to handle the image loading for you, asynchronous, including the scaling. Picasso can use the `Uri` directly without any of the flawed `selectedImagePath` stuff. Then, all you need is the `getType()` call to get the MIME type of the image. Your entire `requestCode == SELECT_FILE` block will be replaced by 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: If the user wants to select an image from the gallery, will the result still be stored in data.getExtras().get("data"); ??

Comment: @MotassemJa: "will the result still be stored in data.getExtras().get("data"); ?" -- no. At most, that is used for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, if you do not provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. For `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, the result is in `data.getData()`, which will be a `Uri` pointing to whatever content the user picked.

Comment: There is no method getType() in getContentResolver()

Comment: @MotassemJa: `getContentResolver()` is a method. It returns an instance of `ContentResolver`. And `ContentResolver` has a `getType()` method, as you can tell by [reading the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getType%28android.net.Uri%29).

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [Apache Commons Io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29)
Use FilenameUtils.getExtention() from this lib

```
String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension("/path/to/file/foo.txt");
```

i think this will help you